# Where can I place Login page in Single page Scrolling Portfolio Site in React js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

Actually I am creating portfolio app in React.Now I am facing issue,In the navigation bar,there are six menu(Home,About,Skill,Experience,Contact,Connect) in Single page app.When I click on any menu then I scroll to a particular related component in a Same page.Now Problem arises When I add one more menu at the right hand side which is (Login).I want to achieve that when I clicked on Login then another page Login page will open.When I fill the Username and Password in Login page then I will reach one more page called Dashboard page.On the Dashboard Page,I want to create Some more new component regarding updating my skill,experience,Contact etc.How Can I achieve?Please help me.Thanks in advance.

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvWdK.png)

//App.js File include my all single page Component

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Menu from './Components/Menu';
import Background from './Components/Background'
import Border from './Components/Border'
import Skill from './Components/Skill';
import About from './Components/About';
import Experience from './Components/Experience'
import Image from './Components/Image'
import Contact from './Components/Contact';
import Connect from './Components/Connect';
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './Components/Login'


function App() {


  return (
<div>

    <Menu></Menu>
    <Border></Border>
    <Background></Background>
    <About></About>
    <Image></Image>
    <Skill></Skill>
    <Experience></Experience>
    <Contact></Contact>
    <Connect></Connect>





</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the route to those pages. We give each route either a target `component`, or we can send functions in `render` or `children` that return valid nodes. `children` always returns the given node whether there is a match or not.
BrowserRouter is the router implementation for HTML5 browsers.
Link is your replacement for anchor tags.
Route is the conditionally shown component based on matching a path to a URL.
Switch returns only the first matching route rather than all matching routes.

Below is an example of how it would look like.

```
const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;
const About = () => <h1>About</h1>;


const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>{' '}
      <Link to={{pathname: '/about'}}>About</Link>{' '}
      <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route
          path="/contact"
          render={() => <h1>Contact Us</h1>} />
        <Route path="/blog" children={({match}) => (
          <li className={match ? 'active' : ''}>
            <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
          </li>)} />
        <Route render={() => <h1>Page not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```